# Adjusting GC Overhead Exceeded parameters

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot, memory-leak-detector

I need my Oracle Hotspot to throw an exception `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` much sooner than with the default parameters of `UseGCOverheadLimit`.

By default, OOME occurs when more than 98% of the time is spent in GC and less than 2% of the heap is recovered (described http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom).

For instance, I need my JVM to throw OOME when more than 20% of the time is spent in GC.
Unfortunately, the `-XX:GCTimeRatio=nn` doesn't seem to make a difference.

The reason I need to adjust my JVM in this way is that I'm testing my application whether it contains a memory leak (precisely, I have a memory leak detection infrastructure where I want to test our app on a daily basis) and I don't need my JVM to try as hard as possible to free the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, OOME occurs when more than 98% of the time is spent in GC and less than 2% of the heap is recovered

These two values are configured via `GCHeapFreeLimit` and `GCTimeLimit`

`GCTimeRatio` only defines a soft goal for which the GC heuristics will optimize.

Comment: It seems like this was never implemented for G1 collector (as of Mar 2021): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212084